# How i can use font in wordpress?

Tags: fonts

I have three paragraphs with different fonts and all this must be placed in one editor. I now have a question ... How can I make one paragraph with one font, another with another font and a third with a third?

Comment: You may want to give different css class name to each paragraph and set to use different font to each class in you css file.

Comment: but how to assign these classes to a paragraph?
So I do not understand. For example I am a flattery. Writing an article. I press enter. A new paragraph appears and I need it to be a different font and now how to do it?

Comment: I am guessing you are using gutenberg editor. Once you click enter and you are already in new paragraph. Right handside in block section > advanced you should see "Additional css" input like in this image https://imgur.com/a/SvrOFot

Comment: there is not such an editor. He is different. Such as yours I only have in pages and posts, but in self-created sections and in ACF, I have some other ... classic

Answer (score 1):

On Wordpress, all paragraphs look the same.
But it is also true that on Wordpress, you can change everything.

So there are a few solutions but you will need a little development.

Personally, I would use [Flexible Content fields of the ACF plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/).

Hoping I could help you.